# Can Rundeck have a job that executes a part as "dispatch to node" and a part as "execute locally"

Tags: jobs, rundeck

Good Evening,

I have a job with two parts :

1. on a remote server run a command
2. Once complete, on the local rundeck server run an scp -3 command

Example Rundeck Job :
(part one)

1. choose from remote-server1, remote-server2 or remote-server3 (as ${option.remoteserver} )
2. execute the following command on the node (server) : "dstat --output dstat.output.csv 10 1"

(part two)

- scp -3 ${option.remoteserver}:/home/rundeck/dstat.output.csv local-server:/home/rundeck/${option.remoteserver}_dstat.output.csv

In the 'nodes' tab I have "dispatch to nodes" selected.
The problem I have is that part one works perfectly, but part two is also sent to the remote server, whereas I need that to be "execute locally"

Is it possible to have part one set as "dispatch to nodes" but have part two set to "execute locally"

Answer (score 1):

You can create two jobs, the fist pointing to the remote node (using "dispatch to nodes") and the second to the local node. Then, you can create a parent job that references those jobs using the [job reference step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#job-reference-step). [Here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rundeck-discuss/C8KpsqBupmo/WzNj9dMyBwAJ) you have a good example.

Job to remote node:

```xml
    <joblist>
        <job>
            <defaultTab>summary</defaultTab>
            <description></description>
            <dispatch>
                <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
                <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
                <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
                <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
                <threadcount>1</threadcount>
            </dispatch>
            <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
            <id>53b304fe-c68c-40ed-a5cb-e8af9de75a99</id>
            <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
            <name>JobToNodeONE</name>
            <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
            <nodefilters>
                <filter>name: node00</filter>
            </nodefilters>
            <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
            <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
            <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
                <command>
                    <exec>uname -a</exec>
                </command>
            </sequence>
            <uuid>53b304fe-c68c-40ed-a5cb-e8af9de75a99</uuid>
        </job>
    </joblist>
```

Job to local node:

```xml
    <joblist>
        <job>
            <defaultTab>summary</defaultTab>
            <description></description>
            <dispatch>
                <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
                <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
                <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
                <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
                <threadcount>1</threadcount>
            </dispatch>
            <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
            <id>b5e54476-a663-4fed-a541-c270a0295265</id>
            <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
            <name>JobToNodeTWO</name>
            <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
            <nodefilters>
                <filter>name: localhost</filter>
            </nodefilters>
            <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
            <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
            <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
                <command>
                    <exec>uname -a</exec>
                </command>
            </sequence>
            <uuid>b5e54476-a663-4fed-a541-c270a0295265</uuid>
        </job>
```

Parent job:

```xml
    <joblist>
        <job>
            <defaultTab>summary</defaultTab>
            <description></description>
            <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
            <id>858a3558-ce1f-4814-a483-3162e2ea381b</id>
            <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
            <name>ParentJOB</name>
            <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
            <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
            <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
                <command>
                    <jobref name='JobToNodeONE'>
                        <uuid>53b304fe-c68c-40ed-a5cb-e8af9de75a99</uuid>
                    </jobref>
                </command>
                <command>
                    <jobref name='JobToNodeTWO'>
                        <uuid>b5e54476-a663-4fed-a541-c270a0295265</uuid>
                    </jobref>
                </command>
            </sequence>
            <uuid>858a3558-ce1f-4814-a483-3162e2ea381b</uuid>
        </job>
    </joblist>
```

Also, you can pass options values between jobs using arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the job. At the bottom of the "Node Steps" there is an option for "Local Command". That will run locally even when the previous step was a remote command. It will also have access to the standard set of node variables.